# Numpy.piecewise with number of conditions/functions as variable

Tags: python, function, numpy, piecewise

```
n = len(x_coords)
conditions = [x_coords[i] <= x <= x_coords[i+1] for i in range(n-1)]
functions = [f(x,i) for i in range(n-1)]

def g(x):
    return np.piecewise(x, conditions, functions)
```

‘x_coords’ is just a list of x_coordinates between which I define different functions

When I run this code I get the error “‘<=‘ not supported between instances of ‘float’ and ‘list’ ”

I think I know what the problem is - that the elements in the lists I create are statements rather than values. However, I don’t know how to get around this as I need a list of condition statements and functions for the

```
np.piecewise
```

function parameters

Answer (score 0):

Just use np.arrays instead of a list as this operation is not defined for built-in list. do:

```
x_coords = np.array(x_coords)
```

You also may need to split the conditions:

```
conditions = [ (x_coords[i] <= x) & (x <= x_coords[i+1]) for i in range(n-1)]
```